# Status Indicator of successor task

Tags: ms-project

I have inserted the column of Status in the MS project.

The predecessor task is running late and will take time due to delays. However, i do not want the successor task status to show late in such cases where the dependency is on finishing the predecessor task.

Comment: It sounds like you want the status of the task to be driven by the elapsed time for the task versus the estimated time for the task, rather than being driven by start and end dates. So if it starts late and ends late, that's OK as long as the actual duration isn't longer than you originally forecast. Is that correct?

Comment: This sounds counter-intuitive. If you have a project (not just a continuing process) where a scheduled task is delayed because its predecessor is late, how is the scheduled task also not late? I think you need to provide some context here if you want a useful answer.